# Extent Report plugin not working with testng + cucumber

Tags: testing, cucumber, cucumber-java, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I have a complex problem, please read -
I wanted to run the extent report with my framework which is created using cucumber, testng and java.

I am running the testng file to run the test class file which will eventually run the @CucumberOptions and features added in it.

My test class is extended with AbstractTestNGCucumberTests to support testng with cucumber.

Now everything is working fine. basic testng report is getting generated. 
note : I am running some tests parallel and they are also working fine.

Now i wanted to implement the extent report in my framework. Can you tell me how to do it using plugin which which add the logs same as the cucumber statement added in the feature file.

ps : I have gone through some link which shows me how to run the extent report with junit using @AfterClass, but how to use this with testng.

What I have tried -

libraries used - com.aventstack --> extentreports and com.vimalselvam --> cucumber-extentsreport

Error  - cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Couldn't load plugin class: com.vimalselvam.cucumber.ExtentCucumberFormatter

used plugin - plugin = {"com.vimalselvam.cucumber.ExtentCucumberFormatter:output/report.html"}

and code added under @AfterTest is : Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("xml path")

PLEASE HELP !!! 
I wanted to generate extent report which will also support parallel execution.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can help you with your question. You can refer to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to further improve your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run test cases in parallel and want to have  stable extent report, please go for cucumber 4.x.x version and there are 2 ways of implementing extent report in Cucumber

***1. Using Cucumber-JVM 4 adapter for Extent Framework(extentreports-cucumber4-adapter)*** & below are the steps to implement - (Beauty - You do not need to write any code any where to generate report this way except from setting adapter in runner below)

*Add adapter dependency under POM.XML*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

*Add the com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter plugin to the runner.*

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"})
public class RunCukesTest {
    // ..
}
```

*Report Output Directory - ../Project Directory/test-output/HtmlReport*

***2. Adding aventstack dependency under POM.XML***

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

In this workflow, *Do not Add the com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter plugin to the runner.*

Comment: Thank You so much for the answer. I have tried the first case and report is not generated. here I am not using jUnits @RunWith(Cucumber.class) i am using testng and hence I have only CucumberOptions. Can you suggest how to use it with testng. I am not getting any error though but report is not generated.

Comment: Please share your POM.xml if you are following first case then delete other extent dependencies and keep only adapter one.

Comment: My POM.xml has only one dependency related to extent report. But how to use this with testng. because i dont have @RunWith(Cucumber.class). Thank you for your help. Also one more thing is we are not specifying any report location or any other details. why ?

Comment: For TestNG, please use <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-testng-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>

Comment: HI @DushyantPatil Where u able to resolve this problem. I am facing the similar issues

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using cucumber-extentsreport.*.jar as dependency.
You must specify the extent properties @beforesuite method.
ExtentProperties extentProperties = ExtentProperties.INSTANCE;
extentProperties.setReportPath();

you will also need to add plugin - com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:

Comment: Hi @Sureshmani I tried this but system doesn't allow ExtentCucumberAdapter and ExtentCucumberFormatter together in one project. Can you help out